# Building up interactive app with .NET

Tags: .net-3.5

I am familar developing .net web apps. Try to attempt to build a simple app that more interactive using a bigscreen with desktop. Trying to tap in WPF, Windows Silverlight and Windows Form and not sure which the best approach is.

The data will be displaying list and any update from the server will be get refreshed automatically.  Most important will be like funky grid and not boring grids. Also, after few minutes will change the different funky grid with different query and just rotate that. The application will be divided by 2 sections: admin part where the data key in and public part where user can see the rotating information (no interactive from the user)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "funky" or styled presentation appears to be a key requirement, I'd steer clear of windows forms.

Comment: WPF can do some awesome stuff! Silverlight is primarily targeted at running in the browser, so WPF is probably where you want to go. There are some VERY cool samples out there... there is a medical records sample app they showed at one of the MSDN conferences, which i don't remember the name of, but it had some slick graphics! :)